# Turn a string into a variable

Tags: ios, string, swift, variables

Hello I have a for in loop where elements is the variable being changed and in this case "elements" is a string but there is a corresponding variable out side of the for in loop that has the same name as the string called elements. So what I mean is out side there is a Var time = [some,text,words] and theres a for in loop that calls a STRING named "time" and I would like to know how to convert the string in the for in loop into the variable by some how taking off the "'s (not that simple I know) without specifically saying "time"(the variable) but instead converting the "elements"(which is the string 'time') string into the variable. I hope I was clear enough if I'm not making sense I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to local variables dynamically by their names in Swift. This would break a lot of compiler optimizations as well as type safety if you could.

You can refer to object properties by their names if the class conforms to key-value coding. For example:

```
class X : NSObject {
    let time = ["some", "text", "words"]

    func readWordsFromProp(name: String) -> String {
        guard let list = self.valueForKey(name) as? [String] else {
            return ""
        }
        var result = ""
        for word in list {
            result += word
        }
        return result
    }
}

let x = X()
print(x.readWordsFromProp("time"))
```

In general, there are better ways to do things in Swift using closures that don't rely on fragile name-matching. But KVC can be a very powerful tool